# I need help converting VB.Net code to VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, powerpoint

I have inserted in a slide a listview control. In the next step I tried to display all files and folders + icons, using this code:

```
For Each fileName In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\")
    ImageList21.Images.Add (Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName))
    ListView31.Items.Add (system.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)) , _
        ImageList21.Images.Count - 1)
Next fileName
```

It works perfectly on Visual Studio 2008, but on VBA (that uses VB6), I get loads of errors for example:

> For Each Control variable must be variant or object

Also, this line of code is turning red and reporting an error

```
ListView31.Items.Add (system.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)) , ImageList21.Images.Count - 1)
```

> Expected: end of statement

Can anyone explain how to convert the code to VB6/VBA?

Comment: VB.net (which you seem to be using in your code) and VBA are completely different languages (despite appearing to be similar).  You can't take code developed in VB.net and just drop it into a VBA host like powerpoint.  You need to do your development in VBA if you want to run your code as a powerpoint macro.

Comment: Could you help me please to convert my code to VBA?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this is a good question for you, I don't think it or any answer will be useful to anyone else that can find it so I'll be voting to close it as too localised.

Comment: There is no reason to hang a VB6 tag on it either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the FileSystemObject.
[On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

This is the VBA equiv to your VB.NET code (using FSO):

```
Dim fso, objFolder, objFile, strTemp
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\")
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    'might need some other VBA call to extract an icon from these files
    'ImageList21.Images.Add Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(objFile.Name)
    ListView31.Items.Add objFile.Name, ImageList21.Images.Count - 1)
Next
```

Comment: But what's wrong in my code below? Thanks.

Comment: And also this error:" Run-time error 424. Object required. "  ... i don't understand, why?

Comment: Your error is probably happening on the line: ImageList21.Images.Add Icon...
That line refers to some dotnet libraries that don't exist in VBA.  Comment it out and your error should go away.

Answer (score -2):

That looks like VB.NET code. VBA file handling routines are pretty meh, but you can invoke the FileSystemObject from VBA by adding a reference to it.

You'll want to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". You can do this in the VB editor I believe (it's been a while).

The code example by tgolisch should be a good starting point. Just make sure you have the reference set.

Comment: The code by tgolisch does not require any reference to be set: setting a reference is not needed if you use late binding.

Comment: If you want to set the references (for early binding) you do it with the Tools/References menu option.